# C++ limit data on tcp connection

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, binary-data, bandwidth

I wrote a simple `tcp/ip` connection between a client and a server in localhost in `c++`. It sends over tcp/ip an array of `unsigned char`. The size of this array is the following:

```
unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*96000000);

//array is filled
```

However when I write on the socket

```
    n = write(sockfd,bytes,96000000);
    if(n<0){
        cout << "error writing"<< endl;
        exit(1);
    } else{
        cout << "bytes written " << n <<endl;
    }
```

the number of bytes written (the `n` variable) that the standard output prints out is `5196978` and not `96000000` as I expected. Why? is there a limit in the number of bytes that I can write in a `TCP /IP` connection? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a limit in the number of bytes that I can write in a TCP /IP connection? How can I solve this problem?

Yes - your TCP stack (likely part of your Operating System) won't simply let your application enqueue an arbitrary amount of data, potentially taking up absurd amounts of buffer memory outside your app.  Instead, it has a limited buffer size and after that's full you're expected to loop around and enqueue more data in the buffer - by further calls to `write` - after some has actually been sent over the network.  So - loop and resend from where the previous send stopped: if your socket's not been set non-blocking, the call will block until more buffer space is available.

Comment: @L.Joe the server side's a little different - you can *either* loop or - on implementations that support it - use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag, see [`recv`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv).

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

There could be several reasons. There might be some sort of physical limitation (hardware). The client buffer could be full. Some sort of implementation limit could have been reached. Some sort of signal could have been received.

> is there a limit in the number of bytes that I can write in a TCP /IP connection?

The limit is around  2^32 bytes.

> how can I solve this problem?

Keep track of how much is sent with each write and keep writing until everything in the buffer has been written.

I did not add a sample as the first question could have been answered by checking the documentation for write(), the second could have been answered with a quick search and the third question has a lot of samples out there already.